# Vue/Laravel How to pass form from blade to vue to use checkValidity

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Made following button made by vue(single component).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" class="button_orange button_big" value="Register" v-show="!isSubmitting" @click="startSubmit">
    <div class="button_disable button_big" v-show="isSubmitting">Register</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isSubmitting: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      startSubmit() {
        if (form.checkValidity()) {
          this.isSubmitting = true;
        }
      },
      reset() {
        this.isSubmitting = false;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Current problem is how to pass the form to vue to use checkValidity() method. laravel blade is the following type source code.
if there is idea how to pass form from blade to vue, please help.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <submit-button></submit-button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with this?

```
document.querySelector("form").checkValidity()
```

(Of course this would require to have this for as the only form on the page, so if you can, you should have an ID on the form and go for something like `document.querySelector("#myForm01").checkValidity()` instead.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 
About the way we access form from vue, do we have only the way using DOM access?

Comment: Definitely not. Use ref="myForm" in the form tag and then in a Vue method you can use this.$refs.myForm which will refer to the form